# Uploading image and audio to AWS S3

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS S3 and wonder how do I upload an image from my local computer to the S3 Bucket using VueJS(axios) to Laravel.

So far in my laravel api, I tried uploading it in the S3 using this one line of code.

In my **VueJS**, I have this function that sends a `Request` to my api in laravel:

```
uploadphoto() {
    var d = new Date();
    var type_name = this.original_filename.split('.'); //some computed property I dispatched after uploading a file that gets the file's original name and extension.
    const form = new URLSearchParams();
    form.append('file_name', type_name[0]+('-')+d.getTime()+'.'+type_name[1]); //this gets; filename-<milliseconds>.png/jpg/mp3(extension)
    form.append('file', this.ia_attachment[0].file) //base64 encoded file /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4gxY...
    this.axios.post('uploadimage', form, {
        headers: ''
    })
}
```

and in my **ImageController**, I have this...

```
public function uploadimage(Request $request) {
    
    $disk = Storage::disk('s3');
    $disk->put('public/images/'+$request->file_name, base64_decode($request->file));
}
```

When I send the POST request, it gives me error saying:

```
ErrorException: A non-numeric value encountered in file C:\Users\me\Desktop\myproject\app\Http\Controllers\ImageController.php on line 33
```

...and also, should there be a need to upload a base64 encoded file or is there any other way to upload it?

Comment: What is line 33 ? Secondly, I will recommend you to first test your code by hardcoding the values  something like put('public/images/abc.txt ) so that u will know exactly where the problem is

Comment: @DeepakSinghal `$disk->put(..)` is the line 33

Comment: Did u try hardcoding the values on line 33